# invalid python colon error syntax

Tags: python

```
class Personaje:
    def__init__(self,name):
        self.name=pepe
        self.type=warrior
        self.health=100
        def eat(self,food):
            if(food=="manzana"):
                self.health-=10
            elif(food=="leche"):
                self.health+=5
            else(food=="mondongo"):
                self.health+= int(0.0001)
```

im getting invalided syntax on the (self.name): <<

Comment: Is it a `NameError`? What's a `pepe`?

Comment: You are missing a space: `def__init__(self,name):` should be `def __init__(self,name):`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I REALLY APpRECIATE IT! for real!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem 1

Take a look at the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-3873e72b95ad>", line 3
    def__init__(self,name):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There should be a space between `def` and `__init__` so the definition of your `__init__` function should be:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    # ....
```

#### Problem 2

The else statement does not take any expression like `if` or `elif` do, so that results in this syntax error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-661f08a520ce>", line 12
    else(food=="mondongo"):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`else` means everything else, so if you want it to only apply to "mondongo" you should use another `elif` there.

#### Problem 3

Function `eat` is defined inside the `__init__` function causing:

```
<ipython-input-22-9789ced9c556> in <module>()
----> 1 p.eat('leche')

AttributeError: Personaje instance has no attribute 'eat'
```

if you unindent the function (move left by 4 spaces) then eat will be defined inside the class and not the init function.  So the basic structure should be indented like this:

```
class Personaje:
    def __init__(...):
        pass
    def eat(...):
        pass
```

#### Problem 4

Not setting the Personaje name to the one specified in the `__init__` function.  If you want to default name to `pepe` and type to `warrior` I suggest you change your init function to look like this:

```
def __init__(self, name="pepe", type="warrior"):
    self.name = name
    self.type = type
    self.health = 100
```

Your final `Personaje` class now should look something like this:

```
class Personaje:

    def __init__(self, name="pepe",type="warrior"):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.health = 100

    def eat(self, food):
        if(food=="manzana"):
            self.health -= 10
        elif(food=="leche"):
            self.health += 5
        else:
            self.health += int(0.0001)
```

Comment: How did I miss that *facepalm*

Comment: and the indentation of the class method  `def eat` is off too.

Comment: and both `pepe` and `warrior` should throw `NameError`s (unless they're globally defined, I suppose. It's at least possible that IMMEDIATELY after the posted code, `Personaje.__init__` calls `eat` :)

Comment: Yes, I assume this class is only part of the overall python file.

Comment: @Victor Castillo Torres I think it is unclear if pepe and warrior are supposed to be the default values or variables that are defined somewhere else in the file.